# Where to place a webcron file in CakePHP folder structure?

Tags: cakephp, cron

I have a PHP script that is to be run indirectly by cron daemon through the web server. I'm confused about where to place this file in the CakePHP folder structure.

Should I place it in any controller and give it access from outside? (i.e without login check)

Or is it better to place this script outside my cake project folder and put it anywhere in localhost?

Comment: Is it a command line script? Your mentioning of *access from outside* suggests it isn't :-?

Comment: Its a php file. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'll rephrase my question: is it a command line script written in the PHP language? Or is it a PHP script that needs to run through a web server?

Comment: Its the second one: PHP script that needs to be run through a web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script does not utilize CakePHP goodness (pure PHP) just place it in a directory not accessible to the public, for example 'Cron' on same level as 'App'.

If it does use CakePHP, place it as an action in the appropriate controller. You can add a custom prefix to the action e.g. 'cron', then override AppController and if the prefix is 'cron', check the IP address. Deny access if it isn't localhost.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a file that's independent of CakePHP and you need to access it from the public Internet, put it in the `webroot` folder.